# Using scrollHorizontally as a style attribute

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I have an `EditText` that I want to be a horizontally scrollable component.

I've found that I can make the contents of the `EditText` side scrolling by programmatically using

```
mEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

No problem. However I want all of my components of this type to be side scrolling, to this end I added the following attribute to my `EditText`'s style:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.EditText.SingleLine">
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item> 
</style>
```

and attached this to the `EditText` like so:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText.SingleLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

(Adding other styles such as `android:textSize` to this styleable as a debug step takes effect, so the style is being picked up correctly)

Even adding the `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` to the EditText xml directly doesn't take effect.

Does anyone understand why this particular attribute refuses to work?

***Edit 1***

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.EditText.SingleLine">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse.HorizontalScrolling</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse.HorizontalScrolling">
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>
```

Doesn't work. Looking into `TextView` source it uses:

```
    a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    [...]

    case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_scrollHorizontally:
        if (a.getBoolean(attr, false)) {
            setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        }
        break;
```

I can't see any way in which this wouldn't work - can anyone else?

Comment: If I really wanted to solve this, I'd subclass the EditText and start debugging the attributes

Comment: can't you just get it automatically by setting: `android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"`

Comment: @inner_class7 Get what by adding those...? Horizontal scrolling? AFAIK it crop's no?

Comment: if i set these attributes on an edit text, it scrolls horizontally when the text in the field is longer than the width of the screen size or view